# Do products exist to hedge against specific building materials?

Tags: hedging

I was wondering whether there exist product to hedge against specific building materials? Up to now I have not yet found a suitable product to hedge against cement or glass?

If not, how would one hedge against the price increases of these products? I do not believe that there exist products to hedge against price of sand for example (used in glass making). In addition, I understand we can buy cement making companies or glass making companies, but all these companies have non-building material related activities, which distort the hedge in my opinion.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the glass price mainly driven by labour and energy (electricity prices) for which instruments exist?

Comment: cement/clinker prices are driven by energy prices. So energy futures may be an imperfect hedge for both glass and cement. Also cement cannot be stored for a long time, but rather is produced when there is demand. I recall there were attempts on trade cement/clinker futures on some commodities exchanges in China and India that didn't quite work out, e.g. https://www.livemint.com/Money/VTJ6bzfSajLIbpfySB2nLJ/NCDEX-for-futures-trading-in-cement.html